# How do I combine AWS API Gateway and Application Load Balancer for HTTPS outside of us-east-1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-api-gateway, aws-certificate-manager

I am attempting to route traffic through the AWS API Gateway to my ECS containers running in a private subnet via an Application Load Balancer running in a public subnet. Using plain old HTTP everything works perfectly fine, but now I want to add transport layer security (TLS, fka SSL) to the communication between the gateway and the load balancer. In other words, terminate SSL at the load balancer.

- I've got a custom domain name configured and working on my gateway that was already exposing a HTTPS endpoint.
- I've got a HTTPS listener configured on my load balancer, which scolds me for having a dodgy certificate but if I ignore the warning when I hit it directly I get routed to my service correctly. Thus load balancer routing is correct.
- When I attempt to point the gateway to the balancer it breaks. Furthermore, it seems the I can only use certificates for custom domain names that are in the us-east-1 region. At present they are failing with the following error in CloudWatch (details obscured for privacy).

> Execution failed due to configuration error: Host name
>   'XXXXXXXXX-lb-XXXXXXXXX..elb.amazonaws.com' does not match the
>   certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=)

Given my load balancer is *not* in the us-east-1 region how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: *Furthermore, it seems the I can only use certificates for custom domain names that are in the us-east-1 region.*  I think you're confusing two constraints.  For your balancer, you need a cert in the balancer region.  For API-GW, you probably needed a cert from us-east-1 because of the API-GW dependency on CloudFront, which only interfaces with ACM in us-east-1.  You can't use dodgy certs behind API-GW,  by design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign a custom domain name to the load balancer. Then assign a valid SSL certificate to the load balancer using the ACM service. Then reference the load balancer using the custom domain name.

Comment: Perfect! Up and running. Finally found the following AWS documentation which helped, too: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/using-domain-names-with-elb.html. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me how to integrate API gateway with application load balancer? I have integrated ECS with ALB, now I want to add API gateway in front without lambda. so I got confused how to connect API gateway with ALB..

Comment: @MihirShah ask a separate question on here instead of tagging onto an existing question.

Comment: This worked! Saved by the Classic Load Balancer, a DNS A Record + Alias.